# discarding qualifier when passing a struct

Tags: c, pointers

I am having one of those "discards qualifiers" cases that I cannot figure out.  I have code that empirically functions until I try to get rid of the warning.  Here's the error:

```
filter.c:28:21: warning: passing 'const filterentry [1]' to parameter of type
  'struct filter_matchbuffer *' discards qualifiers
  [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
filterServiceBuffer(filterinparsermap);
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In the code below, I have a series of text string filters that are text that is paired with a function.  For instance, when I see the "$GPRIP" string, it copies the message.  Anyway, there's whole series of these pairs in filterinparsermap[].

```
#define FILTER_COPY 3
enum
{
    FILTERFUNCTION_COPY = FILTER_COPY,
#define FILTERFUNCTION_COPY FILTERFUNCTION_COPY
};

struct filter_matchbuffer
{
    int indexofstring;
    int filterbehavior;
    const char *const strforcomparison;
};
typedef struct filter_matchbuffer filterentry;
#define FILTERTEXTENTRY(num, behavior, x) \
    {                                     \
        num, behavior, #x \
    }

const filterentry filterinparsermap[] = {
      FILTERTEXTENTRY(1, FILTER_COPY, "$GPRIP")};

void filterServiceBuffer(struct filter_matchbuffer p_filtermap[])
{
}

int main(){
filterServiceBuffer(filterinparsermap);
return(0);
}
```

I would really like to get rid of the error, but I just cannot seem to get my struct and pointer types to agree and still have the code compile.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: " to get rid of the error," --> Try `void filterServiceBuffer(struct filter_matchbuffer p_filtermap[])` --> `void filterServiceBuffer(const struct filter_matchbuffer p_filtermap[])`.  If that causes another issue, we need an compile-able example

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'll try it.  The code does compile.  I tried to post a minimally functional example.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica and that fixed it as well.  I cannot believe it was so mundane.  I swear that I tried that before I posted. :/

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica can you convert your comment into an answer so that I may accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to get rid of the error ("discards qualifiers" )

Edit function signature to accept a pointer to `const` data.

```
// void filterServiceBuffer(struct filter_matchbuffer p_filtermap[])
void filterServiceBuffer(const struct filter_matchbuffer p_filtermap[])
```